# Pandas, comparing different length dataframes for a value *range* & writing back to original df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, between

I have two dataframes with different index lengths to compare.

df1: daily low stock prices (this has one low price per day)

df2: daily purchases of stock (this has more than one buy per day)

I'd like to iterate through the rows of the *price* per *date* in df2 checking if df2[Price] > df1[low] and adding YES in df2[In_range] for that row if it is, and NO if it's not.

I've included a screen shot of the tables and simple diagram with the description do you can see.
[Picture of tables with simple diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHN2A.png)

If you need more clarification please let me know :)

Thanks,
Elliot

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate on or rephrase the sentence starting with “What i’m looking for”? I’m not 100% clear on what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, never post images of your data. Copy-paste the text. This way people can easily grab it and use it to test their solutions.

Comment: @ Alexander Cecile I've updated and simplified it there with a diagram, The data is sanitised.

@ Valentino I couldn't find a good way to paste the text in a neat looking way from xlsx to csv. I'll go to a quick check on how, to make things easier  on everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to add the column 'low' to the second dataframe.

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on = ['Company', 'time'])
```

And then performing the check would be simple in a single dataframe

```
df2['In range'] = df2['Price'] >= df2['low']
```